# How to pass username and password in TeamCity REST API

Tags: authentication, rest, teamcity

I've just started to experiment with the TeamCity REST API. I've been some of the documentation about what types of commands I can call, etc, but one thing which is not mentioned is how to pass a username and password to the API.

I've not been able to find examples of this; so can someone help me out please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

like this:

```
http://user:pass@server:port/app/rest/..... etc
```

I found that on the [EAP Docs Site](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=45252915)

Comment: Many thanks for that. Hmmm, not sure if I like the idea of including the username and password in the url like that. Will ask the team if they have a https: available for the TeamCity server.

Comment: I think you can use SSL on Team city.

Comment: Even with SSL (https), does that not still mean I need to pass username and password in the url, which means I'm not better off? Sorry for sounding such a newbie here, this stuff is new to me.

Comment: Cheers for that explanation, much appreciated :)

Comment: updated docs here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Accessing+Server+by+HTTP

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for Sangha's answer. Just one more supplement.

Please remember to encode user id and password using **Base64.**

Comment: only needed, if you've got special chars in your id/pwd