# Error when using powershell script to generate changelog file from Teamcity build

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I am using the following script to generate a changelog from teamcity builds.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Generates a project change log file.
.LINK
    Script posted over:
    http://open.bekk.no/generating-a-project-change-log-with-teamcity-and-powershell
#>

# Where the changelog file will be created
$outputFile = "%system.teamcity.build.tempDir%\releasenotesfile_%teamcity.build.id%.txt"
# the url of teamcity server
$teamcityUrl = "%teamcity.serverUrl%"
# username/password to access Teamcity REST API
$authToken=[Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("%system.teamcity.auth.userId%:%system.teamcity.auth.password%"))
# Build id for the release notes
$buildId = %teamcity.build.id%

# Get the commit messages for the specified change id
# Ignore messages containing #ignore
# Ignore empty lines
Function GetCommitMessages($changeid)
{
    $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("$teamcityUrl/httpAuth/app/rest/changes/id:$changeid")     
$request.Headers.Add("AUTHORIZATION", "$authToken");
$xml = [xml](new-object System.IO.StreamReader $request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()    
Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Select-Xml $xml -XPath "/change" |
    where { ($_.Node["comment"].InnerText.Length -ne 0) -and (-Not $_.Node["comment"].InnerText.Contains('#ignore'))} |
    foreach {"+ $($_.Node["user"].name) : $($_.Node["comment"].InnerText.Trim().Replace("`n"," "))`n"}
}

# Grab all the changes
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("$teamcityUrl/httpAuth/app/rest/changes?build=id:$($buildId)")
$request.Headers.Add("AUTHORIZATION", "$authToken");
$xml = [xml](new-object System.IO.StreamReader $request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()

# Then get all commit messages for each of them
$changelog = Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Select-Xml $xml -XPath "/changes/change" | Foreach {GetCommitMessages($_.Node.id)}
$changelog > $outputFile
Write-Host "Changelog saved to ${outputFile}:"
$changelog
```

When I run this, the file is generated, but it is always empty. When I look at the build log I see the following error message from the powershell build step.

[image: Error]

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong and what I need to change to make this step work?

Comment: When looking at the TeamCity REST api docs, there is nothing about an `Authorization` header. They only mention user/password authentication.

Comment: So are you saying I should actually use a username and password instead of those variables?

Comment: The answer over on this other question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20903962

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These error observed on with teamcity version 10.
 Replace Add("AUTHORIZATION", "$authToken")  with
 Add("AUTHORIZATION", "Basic $authToken")

These code worked for me version 10 with build number 50574.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Generates a project change log file.
.LINK
    Script posted over:
    http://open.bekk.no/generating-a-project-change-log-with-teamcity-and-powershell
#>

# Where the changelog file will be created
$outputFile = "%system.teamcity.build.tempDir%\releasenotesfile_%teamcity.build.id%.txt"
# the url of teamcity server
$teamcityUrl = "%teamcity.serverUrl%"
# username/password to access Teamcity REST API
$authToken=[Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("%system.teamcity.auth.userId%:%system.teamcity.auth.password%"))
# Build id for the release notes
$buildId = %teamcity.build.id%

# Get the commit messages for the specified change id
# Ignore messages containing #ignore
# Ignore empty lines
Function GetCommitMessages($changeid)
{
    $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("$teamcityUrl/httpAuth/app/rest/changes/id:$changeid")     
$request.Headers.Add("AUTHORIZATION", "$authToken");
$xml = [xml](new-object System.IO.StreamReader $request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()    
Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Select-Xml $xml -XPath "/change" |
    where { ($_.Node["comment"].InnerText.Length -ne 0) -and (-Not $_.Node["comment"].InnerText.Contains('#ignore'))} |
    foreach {"+ $($_.Node["user"].name) : $($_.Node["comment"].InnerText.Trim().Replace("`n"," "))`n"}
}

# Grab all the changes
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("$teamcityUrl/httpAuth/app/rest/changes?build=id:$($buildId)")
$request.Headers.Add("AUTHORIZATION", "$authToken");
$xml = [xml](new-object System.IO.StreamReader $request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()

# Then get all commit messages for each of them
$changelog = Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Select-Xml $xml -XPath "/changes/change" | Foreach {GetCommitMessages($_.Node.id)}
$changelog > $outputFile
Write-Host "Changelog saved to ${outputFile}:"
$changelog
```