# TeamCity - Unable to authenticate via API

Tags: c#, rest, authentication, teamcity-9.0

I've been struggling with authentication in TeamCity through the API lately. I can access the resources directly in my browser (http://usr:pw@teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/...), but doing so programmatically returns 401-Unauthorized.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://user:pwd@teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/projects");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        try
        {
            request.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
             WebResponse response = request.GetResponse(); //Returns 401:Unauthorized
```

I can use guestAuth(http://teamcity:8111/guestAuth/app/rest/projects) without any problem, so there should not be any problem with the WebRequest itself.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: .you should sent the client credentials.then only will be response sucess

Comment: I saw one example here which I thought was sufficient..(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017686/how-to-pass-username-and-password-in-teamcity-rest-api)

Comment: @...this curl request look at this example ..esspecially for 'CreateHttpClient'  https://github.com/stack72/TeamCitySharp/blob/master/src/TeamCitySharp/Connection/TeamCityCaller.cs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to add your credentials and then make request.it will be get what you need.

```
    var username = "abc";
    var password = "123";
    var encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Created the request based on another answer here, but I guess I'm using it in the wront context..